# MahApps setting style based on existing style has strange output

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I copyied MahApps `DataGrid`'s source code and It works fine if I change directly on the style such as setting `HorizontalAlignment` from left to right. But if I did

```
 <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
     x:Key="MetroDataGridColumnHeader1">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
 </Style>
```

and replace the `MetroDataGridColumnHeader` with the new `MetroDataGridColumnHeader1` inside DataGrid style, It gives strange output. Metro effects disappears.Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: how do you replace the `MetroDataGridColumnHeader`?

Comment: @punker76 The original `x:key MetroDataGridColumnHeader` is defined in a summary style of `DataGrid` as `<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeaderRight}" />` I just changed it to the new one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` not the `HorizontalAlignment`.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
        x:Key="RightAlignmentMetroDataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need you @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565203/mahapps-datagrid-lost-its-scrollerviewer-style